# Please provide at least one recipient email address:-Mailer error while using php mailer

Tags: php, sql, email, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer on my website, but it returns an error:

You must provide at least one recipient email address.
I've checked out the following pages looking for answers:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/441
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/429

None of those solved my problem.

This is the way it's set up:

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","sar","siarth2");
mysqli_select_db($conn,"test");
$Email=$_REQUEST["Email"];
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from user where Email='$Email'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

  $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
  $mail->Username = "sidban5679@gmail.com";
  $mail->Password = "password";
  $mail->Port =466;
  $mail->From = "sidban5679@gmail.com";
  $mail->FromName = "Sidharth";
  $mail->AddAddress($row["Email"]);

  $mail->isHTML(true);

  $mail->Subject = "Password";
  $mail->Body = "<i>this is your password:</i>".$row["Password"];
  $mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";
  if(!$mail->send())
  {
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  }
  else
  {
   echo "Message has been sent successfully";
  }
```

**SQL Code**

INSERT INTO `user` (`Password`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`) VALUES
('friends34', 'Kaser', 'Baddal', 'banh5@gmail.com');

Comment: So, have you checked if `$row["Email"]` contains an email?

Comment: And if it does, is it a valid one? Can you show us?

Comment: You are storing and mailing plain-text passwords. And you have an sql injection problem. You should really rethink this.

Comment: Google SSL port is 465 not 466.

Comment: try to enhance code like this:- https://3v4l.org/dLvZH . Still code is vulnerable to SQL INJECTION. also you need to send password and compare it also in query. As well as save password in encrypted format [use password-hashing for encryption].

Comment: @BudimirSkrtic I have changed the port to 465 then also it is showing same error

Comment: @jeroen I just want to remove this error I am not thinking of sql injection I will think it later.

Comment: Can anyone of you tell what should I do

Comment: "I am not thinking of sql injection I will think it later" - welcome to the world of technical debt...

Comment: @Synchro Can you tell what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check that if your `$Email` and `$row['Email']` is returning any valid email address or not. 
you can try once with a hard coded recipient.

`$mail->AddAddress('receipient@example.com');`

I guess from your code, `$Email` and `$row['Email']` are same value. so if `$Email=$_REQUEST["Email"];` is getting valid email, you can use -
`$mail->AddAddress($Email);`

Comment: It's not working. It is showing the same error again

Comment: $mail->Port =466; change the port to 465 for SSL

Comment: I have changed the port as well to 465 then also it is showing same error

Answer (score 0):

On top of the wrong port number, SQL injection vulnerability, plain-text passwords, that you're using an outdated version of PHPMailer, and have based your code on an obsolete example, you're not doing any error checking on the email address. Try this:

```
if (!$mail->addAddress($row['Email'])) {
    exit(htmlspecialchars($row['Email']) . ' is not a valid email address.');
}
```

(`htmlspecialchars()` is there to avoid adding an XSS vulnerability for a perfect score!)

Comment: It is now showing: it is not a valid email address but when I see my database I am able to see the email address.

Comment: In new version there is no PHPMailerAutoload.php so what to use instead of that

Comment: [Read this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940509/how-should-i-upgrade-from-phpmailer-5-2-to-6-0).