# Problem with PHPMailer: require(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a problem with setting up PHPMailer. It was working before, but now all of a sudden it stopped and this is the error I'm getting:
`PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '../src/PHPMailer.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php53/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/cpanel/ea-php53/root/usr/share/php') in /home/pandatra/site.com/contacts_form/contact_form.php on line 9`

Here is the code in contact_form.php:

```
<?php

    include 'config.php';

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

    require ''.$d['include_path'].'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
    require ''.$d['include_path'].'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require ''.$d['include_path'].'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

  if (isset($_POST['Send'])) {
```

How to fix this? Any ideas? I downloaded version 6.1.7 of PHPMailer.

Comment: You'll need to identify where your PhpMailer is, and whether the paths have changed.

Comment: Hey thanks, for the answer. The paths haven't been changed. I just replaced the old version with the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you mentioned is that, the path in your require is getting Wrong. To avoid this type of problem , you should always use **absolute path**

e.g.

```
    require __DIR__.'/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
    require __DIR__.'/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require __DIR__.'/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

   # use "use" after include or require

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
```

**__DIR__**  is the absolute path of running file's directory.

Comment: Thanks for that! I tried that and I got this error now:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/pandatra/nordinterior.com/contacts_form/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 304`

Comment: Reinstall PHPMailer

Comment: Reinstalled and this is the error I'm getting now:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/pandatra/nordinterior.com/contacts_form/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 166`

Comment: Can you state PHP and PHPMailer version ?

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.29
PHPMailer 6.1.7

Comment: "Compatible with PHP 5.5 and later" check here - https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Ok, I've added 5.2 Stable, used __DIR__ for the path to PHPMailerAutoload.php
`require __DIR__.'/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';`
And I'm getting this error:
`ÐŸÐ¾Ð»ÑƒÑ‡Ð¸ ÑÐµ Ð³Ñ€ÐµÑˆÐºÐ° Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸ Ð¸Ð·Ð¿Ñ€Ð°Ñ‰Ð°Ð½ÐµÑ‚Ð¾ Ð½Ð° ÑÑŠÐ¾Ð±Ñ‰ÐµÐ½Ð¸ÐµÑ‚Ð¾: {$mail->ErrorInfo}`

Comment: Please verify your mail input , or try to log each line to see the actual error

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for the help. It is working now and the emails are sent correctly. SMTPSecure was set to tsl with port 465. After changing the port to 587 it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

> I just replaced the old version with the new one

If you upgraded from 5.x to 6.x, you needed to read either [the readme](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#upgrading-from-52), [the upgrade guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/UPGRADING.md), or [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940509/how-should-i-upgrade-from-phpmailer-5-2-to-6-0) that was specifically created to deal with this issue.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I downloaded PHPMailer 5.2 - Stable and using the examples in GutHub I get this:

Comment: Don't use 5.2 for any new development. All the examples are for the current version (6.x) and will not work with old (5.x) versions.

Comment: Here is the error I'm getting `Warning: require(/contacts_form/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/pandatra/nordinterior.com/contacts_form/contact_form.php on line 5 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/contacts_form/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php53/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/cpanel/ea-php53/root/usr/share/php') in /home/pandatra/nordinterior.com/contacts_form/contact_form.php on line 5`

Comment: Please read the docs I pointed you at. The files you are trying to load no longer exist.

Comment: Here is my code:
`include 'config.php';
require ''.$d['include_path'].'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`

I downloaded PHPMailer 5.2 Stable from github and this my results.

Comment: Just stop. I'm not going to help you use an obsolete version.