# How to fix a PHPMailer __autoload() error?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I use phpMailer for the processing of mail sent from the website. This morning I suddenly got the following message:

> Fatal error: __autoload() is no longer supported, use spl_autoload_register() instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\PHPMailerAutoload.php on line 45

I have PHP 8.0.0 running on the server

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.2', '>=')) {
    //SPL autoloading was introduced in PHP 5.1.2
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=')) {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload', true, true);
    } else {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload');
    }
} else {
    /**
     * Fall back to traditional autoload for old PHP versions
     * @param string $classname The name of the class to load
     */
    function __autoload($classname)
    {
        PHPMailerAutoload($classname);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check all your code would work with PHP8 before upgrading?

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but this answer really helped me a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940509/how-should-i-upgrade-from-phpmailer-5-2-to-6-0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using a very old version of PHPMailer – that code has not been in PHPMailer for 3 years. PHP 8.0 is officially supported as of [PHPMailer 6.2.0](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and make sure you read the upgrade guide.

Comment: Thanks a lot.... When I update PHPMailer 6.2.0 then successfully work. ❤❤❤❤

Answer (score 10):

This is An Edited AutoLoad File in:
PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoload.php

```
function PHPMailerAutoload($classname)
{
    //Can't use __DIR__ as it's only in PHP 5.3+
    $filename = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class.'.strtolower($classname).'.php';
    if (is_readable($filename)) {
        require $filename;
    }
}

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.2', '>=')) {
    //SPL autoloading was introduced in PHP 5.1.2
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=')) {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload', true, true);
    } else {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload');
    }
} else {
    /**
     * Fall back to traditional autoload for old PHP versions
     * @param string $classname The name of the class to load
     */
    spl_autoload_register($classname);
    
}
```

Changes are done here:
**spl_autoload_register($classname);**

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your issue will be resolved by changing
function __autoload($classname) to  function spl_autoload_register($classname)
which has no adverse affect on the output.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Simple but works, thank you