# PHPMailer does not execute code after $mail = new PHPMailer

Tags: php, web, phpmailer

I have made a website on my localhost. After everything was ready to go I hosted the website. However, now PHPMailer seems to cause the trouble. Mails are not sending and it seems like PHP code does not execute after `$mail = new PHPMailer` command. Here is part of the code:

```
if($conn->query($sql)){

  require_once '/home/ziptie/public_html/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  

  $mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = true;
  $mail->isSMTP();                            // Set mailer to use SMTP 
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';              // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                    // Enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Username = 'mygmail@gmail.com'; // your email id
  $mail->Password = 'mypassword'; // your password
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                  
  $mail->Port = 587;     //587 is used for Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server.
  $mail->setFrom('mygmail@gmail.com', 'ZIPTIE');
  $mail->addAddress($email);   // Add a recipient
  $mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML

  $v="http://ziptie.rs/verification-page.php?sifra=$token";
  $body = file_get_contents('/home/ziptie/public_html/verificationemail.html');
  $body = str_replace('promenljiva', $v, $body);
  $mail->Subject = 'Verifikacija kupca, ZIPTIE';
  $mail->Body    = $body;
  $mail->addAttachment("naruzbine ".date("d-m-Y").".zip");
  $mail->send();
  header("Refresh:0; url=https://www.ziptie.rs/verification-page.php");
  //echo '<script>alert("Verifikacioni link je poslat, proverite Vašu mejl adresu.")</script>';
    /*if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message was not sent.';
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }*/
    }
 else{
      echo $conn->error;
    }
```

Does anybody know the solution? Thanks!

Comment: What Error does your PHP throw?

Comment: please share your error as well.

Comment: I got a blank screen after the page is being refreshed. I added some code I found online and in console, I get the following:
POSThttps://www.ziptie.rs/checkout.php
and ERROR 500 but nothing else

Comment: console won't show you PHP errors. you need to [**Read your PHP Error log**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel)

Comment: after your `header()` statement you really, **really** should have a `die();` command.

Comment: It won't help that you're using a very old and unsupported version of PHPMailer.

Comment: Okay, I will add die() after that. I found the error but not sure how to solve it:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /home/ziptie/public_html/checkout.php:28, referer: https://www.ziptie.rs/checkout.php

Comment: I guess I can change it to the latest version?

Comment: Seems like you didn't include the PHPMailer code files into your script properly. Upgrade to the latest version and follow the instructions on the PHPMailer home page

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and post the solution if I get one.

Comment: I found solution in upgrading to PHPMailer 6.3 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940509/how-should-i-upgrade-from-phpmailer-5-2-to-6-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found solution in upgrading to PHPMailer 6.3